# Azure Event Hubs - How to implement a consumer in .Net Core WebAPI?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub, webapi

So, I need to implement a Consumer in a WebAPI (.Net core 3.1) application, and reading the Microsoft Documentations and seeing several videos about it, I got to this solution.

This is an extension method for IServiceCollection, I'm calling it from the Startup.cs to instantiate my Consumer (the connection strings and container names are there for tests only):

```
    private static async Task AddPropostaEventHub(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        const string eventHubName = "EVENT HUB NAME";
        const string ehubNamespaceConnectionString = "EVENT HUB CONNECTION STRING";
        const string blobContainerName = "BLOB CONTAINER NAME";
        const string blobStorageConnectionString = "BLOB CONNECTION STRING";

        string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;
        BlobContainerClient storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobStorageConnectionString, blobContainerName);
        EventProcessorClient processor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, consumerGroup, ehubNamespaceConnectionString, eventHubName);

        processor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEvent.ProcessEventHandler;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessEvent.ProcessErrorHandler;

        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
    }
```

The ProcessorEventHandler class:

```
public static class ProcessEvent
{
    public static async Task ProcessEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray());

        //DO STUFF
        await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync(eventArgs.CancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task ProcessErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //DO STUFF
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This code is working, but my question is: is it okay to implement it like that? Is there a problem if the consumer nevers stops? Can it block other tasks (or requests) in my code?

Is there a better way to implement it using Dependecy Injection in .Net Core?

I couldn't find any example of someone implementing in a WebApi, is there a reason for that?

Comment: Can you help me better understand the scenario that you're looking to solve, from a business context?   As you noted, the processor is typically something that you'd want running persistently not in a transient capacity per-request, which would make hosting as part of a web application not the ideal choice.

Comment: @JesseSquire, the scenario is just as you described. 
It was said to me to implement in the WebAPI as a middleware consumer (such as ServiceBus can run), but I don't know if it's the best way to implement it, or if I should create a processor apart from the Api I am working on.

Comment: It's tough to generalize recommendations without understanding the application context in a bit more depth.  What are you looking to do with the events?  What do they mean to your application/business?  How sensitive is timing for reading them?

Comment: @JesseSquire I need to capture the events and send them to a legacy WebService (SOAP), basically. The process is very basic but of high importance to our business.
We are using EventHub because of the integration with the StreamSets framework. But I think we could use ServiceBus.

Comment: It definitely doesn't sound like WebAPI is the right host, regardless of whether you're using Event Hubs or Service Bus.    In either case, you're going to want to have a platform where you can either run persistently and handle events/messages as the broker exposes them or you can run on a schedule, check for messages, read until the broker is empty and then go back to sleep.   Can you use a service process to host or an Azure Function?   What was making you consider a web application for this?

Answer (score 3):

As Jesse Squire mentioned, WebAPI isn't necessarily the correct method of implementation, but it primarily depends on what your goals are.

If you are making an API that also includes an Event Hub listener, you should implement it under the [IHostedService interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). Your existing `AddPropostaEventHub()` method goes inside the interface's `StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` which is what .NET Core uses to startup a background task. Then, inside your Startup.cs, you register the handler as `services.AddHostedService<EventHubService>();`. This ensures that the long running listener is handled properly without blocking your incoming HTTP requests.

If you don't also have an API involved or are able to split the processes completely, then you should consider creating this as a console app instead of as a hosted service, which further separates the roles of API and event listener.

You didn't mention where you are deploying this, but if you happen to be deploying to an Azure App Service, you do have a few options for splitting the receiver from your API, and in that case I would definitely recommend doing so. Inside of App Services, there is a feature called [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) which specifically exists to handle things like this without making it part of your API. A good alternative is [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp). In that case you don't have to worry about setting up the DI for Event Hub at all, the host process takes care of that for you.

Comment: I have used the same by extending BackgroundService using excuteAsync method. But my hanlder is getting call with the https calls only. It is not running independently inside my webapi project as it is working in console app. In my case my api sending some event to event hub and I have implemented its consumer inside my backgroundservice but this consumer blocking https api request because it is running in the sync of api. Confused to solve this issue.